# How to migrate from GraphQL Transformer v2 to v1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

When using Amplify add api it automatically installs the new GraphQL Transformer v2, but I want to use V1.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by a *feature flag*. You can find the docs [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/feature-flags/#transformerVersion)

You'll want to edit (or create) your `cli.json` file and add the following.

```json
{
  "features": {
    "graphQLTransformer": {
      "transformerVersion": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because when you write amplify push - it gets automatically updated to 2, even if you type in 1